# Can't find windows 10 emulators in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to use any of emulators in Visual Studio Community 2015 RC, but I can't find them.

I've already installed Developer tools for windows 10 and windows mobile emulator, no success.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

[image: Don't have any emulators]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Microsoft describes, you have to [do the following steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913721%28v=vs.8.5%29.aspx) to install all Windows 10 tools and the Phone Emulators during Visual Studio 2015 RC:

- Select **Custom** install
- Expand Universal Windows app development tools
- Select Tools and Windows SDK 10.0.10069
- Click **Next** to continue and follow the prompts to complete the installation

[image]

For Build 10158 there are newer emulators, which can be [downloaded here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=615095).

Comment: have you installed the Pro/Enterprise Edition of Windows 10 and not the Home one? Does your CPU support Hyper-V (SLAT)? Can you install Hyper-V without issues?

Comment: I have installed Windows 10 Pro edition. In my old windows 8.1 Pro I was able to run windows phone 8.1 emulators.

Comment: go to "Turn windows features on&off" and look if Hyper-V is installed

Comment: run msinfo32.exe, save a report, upload it to OneDrive and post a link here.

Comment: please try the SDK/emulator for Build 10166. Does this work?